# JSLint error: "Move the invocation into the parens that contain the function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, compiler-errors, jslint

What does **JSLint** mean by this error? And how should it be rewritten?

`Error: Problem at line 78 character 3: Move the invocation into the parens that contain the function: 
    })(jQuery);`

Answer (score 120, accepted):

To pass JSLint's criteria, it needs to be written like this:

`}(jQuery));`

Though I think that particular criteria is a bit subjective. Both ways seem fine in my opinion.

`(function () {})()` makes a bit more sense to me since you wrap the full function, then call it

`(function () {}())` looks like you're wrapping the result of the function call in a parens ...

Comment: What's JSLint's motivation for doing that?

Comment: May I ask why? Most scripts in jQuery are of the format in the question post.

Comment: @Guffa + @pimvdb - not sure. Crockford usually expands a bit on [this page](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html), but it makes no mention of this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450721/solution-for-jslint-errors/1481517#1481517

Comment: http://jslinterrors.com/move-the-invocation-into-the-parens-that-contain-the-function/ (not written by Douglas) says it's just a (lack of) convention

Comment: You can use the "immed" option from [JSHint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10763615/540352) if you want to allow both syntaxes.