# How can I check if the browser support HTML5 file upload (FormData object) after using FileAPI

Tags: html, angularjs, file-upload, form-data

Hello I have been working in AngualarJS and using File UPload control which works completely fine. Now I have used `FileAPI` to make that working in `IE8/9`.

But now I want to detect if the browser support FormData because I want to restrict only one file at a time.But as I am using FileAPI the method `window.FormData === undefined` is not working as because of that I get something like this in IE8 :

```
function(){return{append:function(a,b,c){this.data.push({key:a,val:b,name:c})},data:[],__isShim:!0}}
```

How can I detect if the browser support `FormData` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a shim and since your shim seems to return an object with a `__isShim` property with a value of `true`, you could check it like this:

```
var isFormDataSupported = window.FormData && !(new window.FormData()).__isShim;
```

---

Alternatively, you could check it before including your shim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isFormDataSupported = !!window.FormData;
</script>
<script src="src/to/your/shim.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but JSLINT throws this error : JSLint : Unexpected dangling '_' in '__isShim'

Comment: **[This "thread"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640173/js-lint-unexpected-dangling-in-fngettrnodes)** explains why and **[that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039587/jslint-reports-unexpected-dangling-character-in-an-underscore-prefixed-variabl)** how to get rid of it. It is just a warning, not an actual problem. Alternatively, you could check `FormData` **before** loading the shim.

Comment: what if I use : if ($window.FormData.toString().indexOf('__isShim') !== -1) {

Comment: It would work as well (although note that `!==-1` means `isNotSupported`).