# difference between jslint and jshint?

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

Which one should I use?

Are they the same thing?

I found: 
"JSLint is a JavaScript program that looks for problems in JavaScript programs. It is a code quality tool."

Comment: Definite duplicate. Read up on the former question.

Answer (score 4):

JSHint is a fork of JSLint. The reasons for the fork can be read for example [here](https://medium.com/@valueof/why-i-forked-jslint-to-jshint-73a72fd3612). Basically the author disagrees in some points with Douglas Crockford on JavaScript coding style.

Using either is a matter of personal preference IMHO. I prefer JSHint, however using either is way better, than using neither :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question a couple of weeks ago and was evaluating both JSLint and JSHint.

Contrary to the answers in the following question:

> [Should I use JSLint or JSHint JavaScript validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803305/should-i-use-jslint-or-jshint-javascript-validation)

My conclusion is not:

> By all means use JSLint.

Or:

> If you're looking for a very high standard for yourself or team, JSLint.

As you can configure *almost* the same rules in JSHint as in JSLint. So I would argue that there's not much difference in the rules you could achieve.

So the reasons to choose one over another are more political than technical.

We've finally decided to go with JSHint because of the following reasons:

- Seems to be more configurable that JSLint.
- Looks definitely more community-driven rather than one-man-show (no matter how cool The Man is).
- JSHint matched out code style OOTB better that JSLint.