# `new Object` vs `Object` in the ECMAScript spec

Tags: javascript, language-lawyer, ecmascript-5

So, I'm looking at the ES5 specification at the definition of what `new Object` and `Object` do. To my surprise:

- `new Object` describes a whole algorithm of how the object constructor works - treating what happens with different kinds of values. Basically calls `ToObject` on non objects - identity on objects and builds on null and undefined.
- `Object` has a special first step for null and undefined where it builds an object and then calls `ToObject` on primitives and identity on objects.

After reading the description a few times - they *seem* identical. However, clearly from the spec they do *something* different. For example in `Array` - calling `new Array` is specified as  [the function call `Array(…)` is equivalent to the object creation expression `new Array(…)` with the same arguments.`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.1)

So - **what is the difference between `new Object` and `Object`? Why were they specified differently?**

For ease - here's a [link to the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.1.1).

Comment: JS room people (namely Jan Drovak) guessed it has to do with host objects but I couldn't figure out one that actually made a difference.

Comment: `new Object` is implementation-defined on host objects. I'd still like to see an example of when it is not an identity.

Comment: Is this going to be one of those famous questions?

Comment: `When Object is called as part of a new expression, it is a constructor that may create an object.` which concerns `If the value is a host object, then actions are taken and a result is returned in an implementation-dependent manner that may depend on the host object.` and this is implementation dependant. `ToObject` - `Object: The result is the input argument (no conversion).` This seems to be the primary difference. Why?  Probably to allow the `implementation dependant` part

Comment: Here are the [tests](https://code.google.com/p/sputniktests/source/browse/trunk/tests/Conformance/15_Native_ECMA_Script_Objects/?r=81#15_Native_ECMA_Script_Objects%2F15.2_Object_Objects%2F15.2.1_The_Object_Constructor_Called_as_a_Function) used for that part of the spec.

Comment: Not an answer , [**but worth** to look at](http://i.imgur.com/uMciWWR.png)

Comment: @RoyiNamir JSLint is [known for being overly opinionated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6803574/129032), so I'm not sure that's admissible evidence. ;)

Comment: @ssube :-) never said it is an evidence , just worth to mention/know/wonder :-)

Comment: Why not ask on https://esdiscuss.org/?

Comment: @FelixKling because as a reader I hate when people do that without researching first - I figured asking here would be a logical third step (after reading the spec again myself and googling). If I don't get an answer here in a day I'll ask there. Although, to be fair I'm not very optimistic by now since the old ES3 spec has the same definitions.

Comment: Ok, I give up https://esdiscuss.org/topic/new-object-vs-object-difference

Comment: 8 hours is too short  ,  to give up :-)

Comment: So now you've had a couple of days and asked the question on `esdiscuss`, what is the answer to `what is the difference between new Object and Object? Why were they specified differently?`?

Comment: Sounds like you are hoping for Brendan Eich to answer. :)

Comment: @Xotic750 Brendan Eich has already probably seen it as he reads everything on https://esdiscuss.org/topic/new-object-vs-object-difference - he probably doesn't remember either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Object(window)` will never clone `window` but `new Object(window)` might. All current -- potentially all known -- implementations just return the same reference, although the spec allows for implementation-defined behavior.

The steps for 15.2.1.1 say:

> 1. If value is null, undefined or not supplied, create and return a new Object object exactly as if the standard built-in Object constructor had been called with the same arguments
> 2. Return ToObject(value).

The definition of `ToObject` (9.9) lists a few types that will be caught by step 1 (in table 14), but for `Object` has a very simple definition:

> The result is the input argument (no conversion).

It explicitly states that the input argument will be returned as-is, so they should be equal references (`===`).

The definition for `new Object` (15.2.2.1) has a similar chain of type-checks in step 1, but the step for objects (1.a) is:

> i. If the value is a native ECMAScript object, do not create a new object but simply return value.
>
> ii. If the value is a host object, then actions are taken and a result is returned in an implementation-dependent manner that may depend on the host object.

That is, for any host object `foo`, the call `Object(foo)` must `=== foo` but `new Object(foo)` may `=== foo`.

Host objects are defined in 4.3.8 to be

> object supplied by the host environment to complete the execution environment of ECMAScript.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7614380/129032) lists a few host objects to include `window`, `history`, etc. Running those through `new Object(foo)` *should* (but doesn't have to) return a different object.

In any case *but* passing a host object, `new Object(foo)` seems to be a more complicated chain that defers to `ToObject` in much the same way as `Object(foo)`.

Unfortunately, 15.2.2.1.1.a.ii states that the "result is returned in an implementation-dependent manner" and has no specifics as to the "actions [that] are taken" and it appears that Chrome will return the same object (equal references) for all of the listed "host objects."

Using this script to check:

```js
var objects = [
  /* Native objects */
  'Object', 'Date', 'Math', 'parseInt', 'eval',
  /* Host objects */
  'window', 'document', 'location', 'history', 'XMLHttpRequest', 'setTimeout'
];

function getDefinedReference(name) {
  if (eval('typeof ' + name) !== 'undefined') {
    return eval(name);
  } else {
    throw new Error('' + name + ' is not defined.');
  }
}

function checkIdentity(name) {
  try {
    var ref = getDefinedReference(name);
    var no = new Object(ref);
    var o = Object(ref);

    console.log(name, ref === no, ref === o, no === o);

    if (ref === o && no !== o) {
      // Make sure ref === Object(ref) but not new Object(ref)
      console.log(name, 'returns different references.');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(e);
  }
}

objects.forEach(checkIdentity);

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  for (var f in window) {
    checkIdentity(f);
  }
}
```

doesn't find any objects where `Object` and `new Object` behave differently. @Xotic750 seems to be right that it can be implementation-dependent, but nobody is using it.

Comment: Can you find one implementation and one host object that differs between `Object` and `new Object`?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum still looking. I strongly suspect this is something the spec allows but nobody is using, but a test suite can't hurt.

Comment: @AwalGarg that two newly created objects are not reference equal - same as `{} === {}`

Comment: @AwalGarg The whole question relies on the second part where it is not null/undefined :-)