# Javascript Object() vs new Object() for ES6

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, constructor, new-operator

I've seen a number of questions about `new Object` vs `new Object()` or `new Object()` vs `{}`, but I'm wondering about what the difference is between `Object()` and `new Object()`? In other words, what's the difference between calling the `Object` constructor with `new` vs not?

I've seen one other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801497/new-object-vs-object-in-the-ecmascript-spec) on StackOverflow, but it's in regards to ES5. I'm wondering about for ES6?

I also ask because MDN on [their page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Object) for the `Object()` constructor states:

> Note: `Object()` can be called with or without `new`, but sometimes with different effects. See [Return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Object#return_value).

But under the "Return value" section on that page, I cannot discern what these "different effects" may be?

Comment: This did not change with ES6 afaik. I'm tempted to close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: At best, they removed the section about special-casing host objects that no implementation was actually using. Did you check the ES6 spec yourself already?

Comment: "*I cannot discern what these "different effects" may be?*" - probably those that are mentioned in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30805762/1048572) to the question you linked - which are none in practice.

Comment: [According to the current spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-constructor), the return values are not different — they both result in an _ordinary object_ when invoked without an argument. Prefer neither (unless you're programming functionally) and instead use a new object literal: `const obj = {};`.

Comment: @Bergi yeah I checked it, but again nothing particularly obvious to me in terms of differences, so I was wondering if there was something I missed, again particularly because MDN seemed to note there was. Also about this being a duplicate, it is ES6, not ES5, in which a number of overhauls were made to JS, so I thought this might be part of one of them. Particularly too [as there was a discussion board](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/new-object-vs-object-difference) linked to by the ES5 question above in which comments about poor and/or outdated wording in the ES5 spec were made.

Comment: @mishar In that case, you might want to [post an answer](/help/self-answer) and file an issue for MDN