# unexpected token < in js

Tags: javascript, django

I was trying to implement a javascript code in my django admin, I have two fields **hard_drives**(id is: `id_hard_drives`) and **no_of_drives**(id is: `id_no_of_drives`). So, I want **no_of_drives** to appear only if **hard_drives** has particular value, like in the example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#id_hard_drives").change(function () {
        if($("#id_hard_drives").val()=="125"){
            document.getElementById("#id_no_of_drives").type=text
        } else {
            document.getElementById("#id_no_of_drives").type=hidden
        }
    });
</script>
```

But, I get an error:

```
Unexpected token <
```

**Update** :

As per GSWV, i have updated the code, but it still used to show same error, so i removed `<script>` tags. The new code looks something like this :

```
(function($) {
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var hardDriveSelector = $("#id_hard_drives");
       hardDriveSelector.on("change", function(){
          if (hardDriveSelector.val() == "H") {
              document.getElementById("id_no_of_drives").type = text;
          } else {
          document.getElementById("id_no_of_drives").type = hidden;
          }
       });
     });
})(django.jQuery);
```

But the code is not being implemented on fly, the script dosen't do anything, do i need to use key up or something on `id_hard_drives`?

Comment: Get an Editor with syntax hilighting and Linter. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803305/should-i-use-jslint-or-jshint-javascript-validation
$(".#id_hard_drives").change(function(){
 if($("#id_hard_drives").val() == 125){
   document.getElementById("id_no_of_drives").type = text;
 }
 else {
  document.getElementById("id_no_of_drives").type = hidden;
 } 
});

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question and remove Thanks and other sentences, because there are not unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have re-written the code for you. Hope this helps! :)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_no_of_drives').hide();
    $("#id_hard_drives").change(function() {
        var driveID = $(this).val();
        if (driveID == '125') {
            $('#id_no_of_drives').show();
        } else {
            $('#id_no_of_drives').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is your fixed code

1) `$("#id_hard_drives")` - no dot before `#id_hard_drives`

2) `document.getElementById('id_no_of_drives')` - no `#` before `id_no_of_drives`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#id_hard_drives").change(function() {
        if ($("#id_hard_drives").val() === '125') {
            document.getElementById('id_no_of_drives').type = text;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('id_no_of_drives').type = hidden;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: === '125' means that value MUST be a string
== 125 is bad style, but will make your live easyer.

Comment: doesn't work guys, its showing error at "<" on first line only