# Different ways to execute IIFE?

Tags: javascript, iife

Is there any difference between

```
(function (){alert('')}    ())
```

vs

```
(function (){alert('')})    ()
```

Both works but when should I use each ?

Comment: No, it's just a style choice. Use whichever you prefer. But note that [JSLint will want you to use the first form](http://jslinterrors.com/move-the-invocation-into-the-parens-that-contain-the-function/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wrapping parentheses are only there to force the parser to parse the construct as a function expression, rather than a function declaration. This is necessary because it's illegal to invoke a function declaration, but legal to invoke a function expression.

To that end, it doesn't matter where the invoking parentheses go. It also doesn't matter how you force the function to be parsed as an expression. The following would work just as well:

```
!function () {
    alert('')
}();

~function () {
    alert('')
}();

// Any unary operator will work
```

If you decide to use the wrapping parentheses (grouping operator), then just bear in mind that [JSLint will tell you to move the invoking parentheses inside](http://jslinterrors.com/move-the-invocation-into-the-parens-that-contain-the-function/). This is simply a stylistic choice and you can ignore it if you want.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, even [`void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) operator works :-)

Comment: @Barmaley.exe I GOT to try it :-)

Comment: Yes, any unary operator will work. Even `void`, `delete`, `typeof`... they just will not be very readable!

Answer (score 1):

They both do the same thing.

JSLint recommends you use the first, with the executing parentheses inside the grouping parentheses, presumably so everything's neatly grouped together.

For what it's worth, I personally think your second example is much clearer as when scanning the code you can see the execution as standing out from the function expression.

Though not a duplicate, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979252/jslint-error-move-the-invocation-into-the-parens-that-contain-the-function) covers similar ground so might be worth a look.