# Javascript Anonymous Closure

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I have read a lot about closures in Javascript
What are those braces for??
I read on [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) which says closure should be defined as

`(function(){...})();`

but on http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html, it says the closure function is

`(function(){...}());`

What's the difference or the latter one is wrong?
what's the purpose of the last ()? Would you put some parameters inside?
I am looking for a good reference.

Edit:
Moreover, there is an example on [Mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

```
var makeCounter = function() {
var privateCounter = 0;
  function changeBy(val) {
    privateCounter += val;
  }
  return {
    increment: function() {
      changeBy(1);
    },
    decrement: function() {
      changeBy(-1);
    },
    value: function() {
      return privateCounter;
    }
  }  
};
```

why the semicolon is needed for this 'function'? If it needs to be invoked immediately after its declaration, a () should be put before the ending semicolon. But there is not.

Comment: It's not a closure, it's an anonymous function.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [What is the difference between those self-executing anonymous function (aka IIFE) implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026909/what-is-the-difference-between-those-self-executing-anonymous-function-aka-iife)

Comment: possible duplicate of [(...()) vs. (...)() in javascript closures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774425/vs-in-javascript-closures)

Comment: It invokes the function. Without it you would just create a function which is never run (and which cannot be run, since you cannot reference it in any way).

Comment: Nobody has answered the primary question on this page. `(function(){...}());` and `(function(){...})();` are the same. The former is Douglas Crockford's preferred method, but the latter is just as valid.

Answer (score 24):

The syntax

```
(function(){...})()
```

is simply an immediately invoked anonymous function. It does not matter how you use your brackets, as the underlying code is a function being declared, and invoked.

Closures are instead used to describe a situation where a function has access to variables declared outside of its scope, accessible via closures

For clarity :

If we have the following function

```
   function hello() {
      alert("Hello");
   }
```

We can call the function with the following

```
hello()
```

Which invokes the function 'hello'. But if we do not wish to give it a name, but still invoke it, then we can do

```
(function hello() {
   alert("Hello");
})()
```

Which will do the exact same as the previous example of calling `hello`

However, in this scenario there is no point in giving the function the name 'hello', so we can simply remove it:

```
(function() {
    alert("Hello");
})()
```

Which is the notation used in your original question.

Comment: I believe so - I am saying both methods of invoking the function expression are the same. And that closures are different to immediately invoked function expressions. Let me know if I misinterpreted the question though :)

Comment: is there any good documentation about the invocation brackets?

Comment: @user1978421 I have added a gradual example of this for you

Answer (score 9):

Your example shows an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), or IIFE. It says to the interpreter:

- here is a function
- it has no name
- keep it away from the global scope ie 'window'
- call it now

Yes, you can put parameters inside the last (). For example:

```
(
    function(username){
        alert("Hello " + username);
    }
)("John Smith")
```

[Closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) are a feature of javascript that allows us to implement [data hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) which is roughly equivalent to private variables in languages like C++ or Java.

```
function getBmiCalculator(height, weight) {
    // These are private vars
    var height = height;
    var weight = weight;

    function calculateBmi(){
        return weight / (height * height);
    }
    return calculateBmi;
}

var calc = getBmiCalculator(1.85, 90);

// calc still has access to the scope where height and weight live.
var bmi = calc();
alert(bmi);
```

In this example, height & weight cannot be garbage-collected until calc is destroyed. The section of memory or "scope" where height & weight exist are "Closed Over"

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. You can also do so:

```
true && function(){ /* code */ }();
0,function(){ /* code */ }();

!function(){ /* code */ }(); // Facebook style
~function(){ /* code */ }();
-function(){ /* code */ }();
+function(){ /* code */ }();

// with new    
new function(){ /* code */ }
new function(){ /* code */ }() // if you need arguments then use brackets
```

Comment: And why is that? This is all correct, but I doubt that a JavaScript beginner will understand why these work.

Comment: Because you can save 1 character in some cases :)

Comment: That's not what I meant. E.g. why do `(function(){ /* code */ }());` or `+function(){ /* code */ }();` work while `function(){ /* code */ }();` or `*function(){ /* code */ }();` don't? What are the characteristics of these lines that allow the function invocation?

Answer (score 2):

the grouping operator can surround the function description as without call parentheses, and also including call parentheses. I.e. both expressions below are correct FE:

```
      (function () {})();
      (function () {}());
```

[Function Expression](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-5-functions/#question-about-surrounding-parentheses)