# What is the difference between these two javascript constructs

Tags: javascript

```
var myObject = (function(){

  var value = 0;

  return {
    getValue: function(){
      return value;
    }
  }

}());



var myObject = (function(){

  var value = 0;

  return {
    getValue: function(){
      return value;
    }
  }

})();
```

The execution seems to return the same Object. i.e., myObject contains

```
  {{
    getValue: function(){
      return value;
    }
  }}
```

in both the cases.

I know something like `(function(){})()` executes because `(function(){})` is an expression which returns a function and the trailing `()` executed the function being returned.

But why does this execute `(function(){}())` ? I was expecting a syntax error here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4979252/139010

Comment: also fwiw this is syntatically valid because the open paren disambiguates from a function expression (as per [the spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.4)), which is why `function(){}()` is a syntax error but `(function(){}())` isn't

Comment: Actually `function(){}()` doesn't seem to be an error. I tried this after posting the question. http://jsbin.com/ayujud/1/edit. And I think that essentially means the enclosing `()` are ignored in the first case. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Both of your examples turn the function definition into a function expression instead of just a function definition.  The JS parser needs to know which it is so it doesn't get it wrong.

Comment: @ShaggyInjun oh yeah true, the assignment makes it unambiguous, I was just trying a naked `function` call, you're right though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrases are functionally identical, the placement of the `()` is something of a matter of taste and I've see directions to do either in favour of the other. Personally I prefer

```
(function() { ... }());
```

That form, creates the function and executes it inside of the parenthesis.

```
(function() { ... })();
```

Creates the function inside of the parenthesis and then executes it.

Answer (score 1):

They are identical.

As for why `(function(){}())` doesn't give a syntax error but `function(){}()` does, I think it's because the parser, when encountering `function` will think it is a function declaration rather than a function expression, but then when it sees `()`, it complains since function declarations have to have a name. But when it sees `(` first before `function` there's no way this is a function declaration, so it thinks it is a function expression.

For `(function(){})()`, you simply enclosed the function expression in brackets before calling it.