# Is there a difference between these two function invocations?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When creating a function and immediately calling it afterward, is there a difference in these two implementations?

```
(function ($) {
     ....some code....
}(jQuery))
```

or

```
(function ($) {
     ....some code....
})(jQuery)
```

Which is the correct method to use?

Comment: No difference and this is a duplicate a zillion times over :)

Comment: @user5013 Do YOU see any difference ?

Comment: The only reason why the brackets are needed is to differentiate between a function declaration(which can't be invoked) and a function expression(which yields a function value, and thus, can be invoked).

Comment: There is no difference.
Here you can see some more explanations - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734055/what-is-the-difference-between-these-2-javascript-declarations

Comment: i prefer the first one, nobody wants to look at your un-sheathed dog balls.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the similiar question. I didn't find it when I first searched for it (probably used the wrong terms).

Comment: jslint favours the first one, though there's no real difference.